# Custom javascript runs before block loaded

Tags: javascript

I have two jQuery calls to modify two divs on a page. One works, the other attempts to work, but the block is lazy loaded, likely using BigPipe. This [helpful doc page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview) is what I'm referring because it explicitly says this is the way to run javascript after the DOM has loaded and all elements are available.
I've given up incorporating it into my custom module and now have broken out the block script to the theme. This is the mytheme.libraries.yml

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/custom.css: {}
global-scripts:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    support/mine.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/jquery.once
```

Here is the mine.js

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  Drupal.behaviors.siteColor = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      let varcolor = {"one": '#694D75', "two": '#AD1A1A', 'white': '#fffff0'};
      var backgroundColor = varcolor[drupalSettings.sitelib];
      $(document).once('siteColor').ajaxComplete(function (context, backgroundColor) {
        jQuery(context).find('#sidebar .title-box').css('.background-color', backgroundColor);
      })}
    }
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

This is not a block generated by a custom module, it's just a block created by the customer in /admin/structure/block

What am I not seeing? How to ensure this runs when the DOM has loaded all the way?

Examining @Clive comment and searching for examples using ajaxComplete() I tried this but finding no love.

I don't think this is a call for the Drupal ajax Commands series as I have the drupalSettings variable from PHP. I just need this to run when the DOM has loaded.

I'm not getting the ajaxComplete() action right. Breakpoint outside the ajaxComplete() wrapper the payload script works in console. Stepping  inside the wrapper, the script is skipped and the block is unaffected after the age loads. However, if I remove the wrapper of .once(), .ajaxComplete() I would expect the payload script to run, but the block is untouched. My revised (again) script is above.

Comment: I guess in your jquery code you should wait for the page to fully loaded and then invoke your functions take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926227/how-to-do-jquery-code-after-page-loading

Comment: _the block is lazy loaded, likely using BigPipe_ That's what you need to confirm. The code you're using does execute on DOM ready (you're using a behavior so all good), so it seems likely the block isn't in the DOM when the DOM is ready - it's there afterwards, loaded by AJAX. If that's the case, you need to hook into an ajax complete event and run the code then. If you want to discount Drupal behaviors as the problem, run the same code in `(function($) { $(function() { ... }); })(jQuery);`. You should see the same result

Comment: *when the mysidebar() function is invoked, jQuery cannot find the block*  - The script should run again when the lazy-loaded block arrives, then with a different `context`, containing lazy-loaded parts of the page. This is the reason attach() operates with this parameter and not with the entire DOM.

Comment: @4k4 Should I see the script run when the lazy-loaded block arrives in the browser console? Lately I see the block loaded but when stepping through the above, nothing occurs to the blocks.

Comment: Yes, put `console.log(context);` inside of the script and you should see different log messages, first one with #document, later one with the lazy-loaded block.

Comment: That helps me on what's in context. Thx. When in breakpoint , the payload script works outside the ajaxComplete. But running w/o breakpoint, it never runs.